# Android browser $(window).scroll not working

Tags: android, jquery

I have a mobile website using jQuery and it $(window).scroll evenet. This works perfectly in Chrome and Safari Mobile, but Android native browser is showing me the middle finger.

I have this simple code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  alert("Scrolled");
}
```

But this alert never appears. I've done alerts in other parts of code, so alert are enabled and I extensively use jQuery so it's also loaded.

I am not sure what's going on here, am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug or limitation in the Android browser, the built-in browser in Android is a lightweight version browser, so some features are not compatible

Answer (score -1):

Simply use:

**$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);**

this will scroll you page to the top.

you can set "scrollTop: " value to set it to any specific TOP position.

dont forget to vote up.

:)

thanks

Comment: Thanks, for this, but, what I actually want is to catch when user scrolls to the bottom on my page and then to call an ajax function.